# How to avoid using GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am developing a small App that uses one GCP API (Natural Language) on Node.js. I followed the instructions here: https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started and downloaded the key file and setup up the env var `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`.

Everything works fine on my local.

Now I want to run it from https://glitch.com/. There, I have a private `.env` which is not shared, but everything else is public. So I cannot upload the key file there as it would be public.

Is there a way to have an env var (which I can keep secret) which all the information that the key file contains?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Two ways I can think of:

1) [Use an API key.](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys) The Natural Language API is one of the APIs that supports using API keys. You can store this key in `.env`.

2) Don't use the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`, but create the client by providing explicit credentials using a JSON.
[This sample](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/blob/master/auth/auth.js#L50) explains how to provide explicit credentials. 
You can store this JSON in `.data`, which is private as [per Glitch's docs.](https://glitch.com/faq#env)

EDIT: changed implicit to explicit

Answer (score 1):

```
// 1. read json by InputStream
InputStream stream = context.getAssets().open("-----.json");
GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(stream);
String projectId = ((ServiceAccountCredentials)credentials).getProjectId();

// 2. build SessionSettings
SessionsSettings.Builder settingsBuilder = SessionsSettings.newBuilder();
SessionsSettings sessionsSettings = settingsBuilder.setCredentialsProvider(FixedCredentialsProvider.create(credentials)).build();

// 3. create SessionsClient
SessionsClient sessionsClient = SessionsClient.create(sessionsSettings)
```